# Looping through an array, calculate the average, and return results in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to write a function that calculates the average of all shoes per designer and returns them in an object like this {designer: 'Brunello Cucinelli', averagePrice: 1025, designer: 'Gucci', averagePrice: 850 }

```
function calculateShoesAverage(inventory){
  var averageObject = {};

  for(var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++){
    var brand = inventory[i];
      averageObject["designer"] = brand["name"];
      averageObject["shoeAverage"] = getShoesAverage(brand["shoes"]);
  }
  return averageObject;
}

function getShoesAverage(shoes){
  sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < shoes.length; i++){
    sum += shoes[i]["price"];
  }
  return sum / shoes.length;
}


var currentInventory = [
  {
    name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},
      {name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},
      {name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},
      {name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Gucci',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},
      {name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}
    ]
   }
 ];
```

This is what I have so far, but it only returns {designer: "Gucci", shoeAverage: 850}, and I don't know how to make it so it returns the other designer too...Thank you!

Comment: Because you're overwriting the `designer` and `shoeAverage` keys on each iteration. Remember, object keys are unique.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a single object with multiple identical properties, because object keys are unique. When you're trying to create this object  `{designer: 'Brunello Cucinelli', averagePrice: 1025, designer: 'Gucci', averagePrice: 850 }`, whenever you add more properties, they replace the previous one, and Gucci is the last, so you only see Gucci.

Map the array to a new a array, and reduce the `shoes` array to get the average:

```js
const currentInventory = [{"name":"Brunello Cucinelli","shoes":[{"name":"tasselled black low-top lace-up","price":1000},{"name":"tasselled green low-top lace-up","price":1100},{"name":"plain beige suede moccasin","price":950},{"name":"plain olive suede moccasin","price":1050}]},{"name":"Gucci","shoes":[{"name":"red leather laced sneakers","price":800},{"name":"black leather laced sneakers","price":900}]}];
 
 const average = (predicate, arr) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, item) => acc + predicate(item), 0) / arr.length;
 
 const result = currentInventory.map(o => ({
  designer: o.name,
  shoeAverage: average(s => s.price, o.shoes)
 }));
 
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to push each `averageObject` to an array, and then return that, like this! That way, it'll match the format of your inventory array.

```js
function calculateShoesAverage(inventory){
  var averageObjects = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++){
      var averageObject = {};
      var brand = inventory[i];
      averageObject["designer"] = brand["name"];
      averageObject["shoeAverage"] = getShoesAverage(brand["shoes"]);
      averageObjects.push(averageObject);
  }
  
  return averageObjects;
}

function getShoesAverage(shoes){
  sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < shoes.length; i++){
    sum += shoes[i]["price"];
  }
  return sum / shoes.length;
}


var currentInventory = [
  {
    name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},
      {name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},
      {name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},
      {name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Gucci',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},
      {name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}
    ]
   }
 ];
 
 console.log(calculateShoesAverage(currentInventory));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in different way but just to fix your code you need to push the object to the arrey:

```
function calculateShoesAverage(inventory){
 //this need to be arrey and not object
  var averageObjects = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++){
    var brand = inventory[i];
    //this is the object
    var averageObject = {};
      averageObject["designer"] = brand["name"];
      averageObject["shoeAverage"] = getShoesAverage(brand["shoes"]);
    //and push it to the array
    averageObjects.push(averageObject);
  }
  return averageObjects;
}

function getShoesAverage(shoes){
  sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < shoes.length; i++){
    sum += shoes[i]["price"];
  }
  return sum / shoes.length;
}


var currentInventory = [
  {
    name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},
      {name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},
      {name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},
      {name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Gucci',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},
      {name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}
    ]
   }
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Object keys are unique, so on each iteration you're replacing the previous keys/values with new ones. Instead try this modification instead. Here you create an object with the key as the brand name, and the value as the average.

```
for (var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
  var brand = inventory[i];
  averageObject[brand["name"]] = getShoesAverage(brand["shoes"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` function like this:

```js
var currentInventory = [{
    name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
    shoes: [{
        name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up',
        price: 1000
      },
      {
        name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up',
        price: 1100
      },
      {
        name: 'plain beige suede moccasin',
        price: 950
      },
      {
        name: 'plain olive suede moccasin',
        price: 1050
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Gucci',
    shoes: [{
        name: 'red leather laced sneakers',
        price: 800
      },
      {
        name: 'black leather laced sneakers',
        price: 900
      }
    ]
  }
];

const calculate_average = (array) => {
  return currentInventory.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    acc[index] = {
      name: curr.name,
      averagePrice: curr.shoes.map(item => item.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)/curr.shoes.length
    }
    return acc
  }, [])
}

console.log(calculate_average(currentInventory))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an array instead of single object.

```
function calculateShoesAverage(inventory)
{ 
 let average = []; 
 for(var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++){
  let averageObject = {};
  let brand = inventory[i];
  averageObject["designer"] = brand["name"];
  averageObject["shoeAverage"] = getShoesAverage(brand["shoes"]); 
  average.push(averageObject) ;
 } 
 return average; 
}
```